# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.VelocityTracker.clear()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.VelocityTracker.clear()' on a null object reference
```

I've searched throughout the code , not using velocity tracker anywhere

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.VelocityTracker.clear()' on a null object reference 
at android.widget.ScrollView.onTouchEvent + 695(ScrollView.java:695)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent + 11777(View.java:11777)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent +2962(ViewGroup.java:2962)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2643(ViewGroup.java:2643)
```

Comment: Same here. Have you found the cause? @coding.cat3

Comment: Got the same issue